# Activity Indicator is not working inside React native deck swiper

Tags: react-native, react-native-deck-swiper

I am using react-native-deck-swiper to show the multiple requests. i have two buttons (Cancel and accept) in each card. When i click any button i want to show the loader on the button until api gives the response. I added the loader but it is not working.

When i simply use View then loader works but not working in react-native-deck-swiper